# Trying to display my media field image in WYSIWYG via twig

Tags: wysiwyg

So I have several images that need to be displayed under a certain image style. I basically made a custom media display view mode, selected an image in the WYSIWYG for a particular page using this display, and now I want to add a class in Twig...

I made a media.html.twig file, renamed it to the custom image style I created in Drupal, and now I'm trying to get the image to display along with the class. In Media > Manage Display, I set the format of my image to URL to image. Now trying to at least print the image before I add the class in TWIG.

{{media.field_media_image.entity.uri.value}}

This code is returning public://image.jpg, but not giving me the full image URL nor printing the exact image I need.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For get full image url try this syntax this is worked for me:

```
{{ file_url(media.field_media_image.entity.fileuri) }}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me too after finding it earlier: {{ file_url(media.field_media_image.entity.uri.value }}